# discord.py on_command event not functioning

Tags: events, discord, discord.py

I am hosting my own local bot, however it seems as 'on_command' does not get invoked when other bots in my server are used. Could this be security restrictions? Is there any way to change this or log other bot commands?

```
@bot.event
async def on_command(ctx):
    print(ctx)
```

Bot is functioning as expected - nothing is printed when a different bot runs a command.

Answer (score 0):

There's no such event that can detect if other bots' commands are being used. The only one that can do something like that is `on_message`, and you also have to code the checks yourself.

Answer (score 0):

The `on_command()` event does exist in discord.py, but it is only invoked *when a command is used on your bot.*

One way to check if a message is sent by a bot is to use the `on_message()` event, like this:

```py
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author.bot:
        # Message is sent by a bot!
        # ...
```

The `message.author.bot` checks if the message's author is a bot.